# What's wrong with this web user control code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a simple web user control and I have registered it on a page to use it.

I have set some required properties and then I am calling a public method of the control

in which i am using some buttons which I have put on my ascx file.

When I use the buttons ( my user control has 12 buttons only ) I get null reference exception.

Following is the code of my user control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MangoCustomControls
{
    public partial class MangoPagerControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        // variables
        private int _totalItemCount;
        private int _currentPageIndex;
        private int _itemsPerPage;
        private int _noOfPages;
        private const int MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 10;
        // event
        public event EventHandler<PagerControlEventArgs> OnPagerItemClicked;
        // methods
        public void BindPager()
        {
            int remainder = _totalItemCount % _itemsPerPage;
            int result = _totalItemCount / _itemsPerPage;

            if (remainder > 0)
            {
                result++;
            }

            _noOfPages = result;

            ShowHideButtonsAndPutTextsOnThem();
        }

        private void ShowHideButtonsAndPutTextsOnThem()
        {
            if (_noOfPages < MAX_PAGE_SIZE)
            {
                btnPrev.Visible = false;
                btnNext.Visible = false;

                for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_PAGE_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    Control ctrl = FindControl(string.Format("btn{0}", i));
                    if (i <= _noOfPages)
                    {
                        ctrl.Visible = true;
                        ((Button)ctrl).Text = string.Format("{0}", i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctrl.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnPrev.Visible = false;
                btnNext.Visible = true;

                for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_PAGE_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    Control ctrl = FindControl(string.Format("btn{0}", i));
                    ctrl.Visible = true;
                    ((Button)ctrl).Text = string.Format("{0}", i);
                }
            }

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            int pageNumber = int.TryParse(btn.Text, out pageNumber) ? pageNumber : -1;
            if (OnPagerItemClicked != null)
            {
                OnPagerItemClicked(this, new PagerControlEventArgs(pageNumber));
            }
        }

        // properties
        public int TotalItemCount
        {
            get { return _totalItemCount; }
            set { _totalItemCount = value; }
        }
        public int ItemsPerPage
        {
            get { return _itemsPerPage; }
            set { _itemsPerPage = value; }
        }
        public int CurrentPageIndex
        {
            get { return _currentPageIndex; }
            set { _currentPageIndex = value; }
        }
    }

    public class PagerControlEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int SelectedPageNumber { get; private set; }

        public PagerControlEventArgs(int selectedPageNumber)
        {
            SelectedPageNumber = selectedPageNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

and the designer file looks like :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MangoPagerControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="MangoCustomControls.MangoPagerControl" %>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn4" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn5" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn6" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn7" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn8" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn9" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn10" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and the code where (on a page )I am calling the control method:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           

                MangoPager.TotalItemCount = 7;
                MangoPager.ItemsPerPage = 2;
                MangoPager.BindPager();

        }
```

I am registering the user control on the web page like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomMango" Namespace="MangoCustomControls" Assembly= "MangoCustomControls" %>
```

and creating MangoPager control like this:

```
<CustomMango:MangoPagerControl  ID="MangoPager" runat="server" 
        ononpageritemclicked="MangoPagerControl1_OnPagerItemClicked" />
```

in the `BindPager()` method I get null reference exception for btnPrev (all buttons are null).

the deigner file looks like :

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MangoCustomControls {


    public partial class MangoPagerControl {

        /// <summary>
        /// btnPrev control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnPrev;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn1;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn2 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn2;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn3 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn3;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn4 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn4;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn5 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn5;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn6 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn6;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn7 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn7;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn8 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn8;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn9 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn9;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn10 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn10;

        /// <summary>
        /// btnNext control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnNext;
    }
}
```

Anyone please tell me why it's null and what should I do to resolve it ?

Comment: Have you ran the code in Debug mode and stepped through the execution to see where the null is?

Comment: Agreed with @TheGeekYouNeed. That's going to be your first step.

Comment: Your OnClick handler is called `OnButtonClick`, but your code behind is called `Button2_Click`.  Also, do you get this exception at design time or run time?

Comment: Yes, it's in the BindPager() method , it says btnPrev is null.

Comment: I get the exception as run time, Button2_Click is the button handler of the page on which I have put my user control...

Comment: And now someone voted -1 for this question, i don't know what's wrong in this question..anyway Mr. TheGeekYouNeed I am new to web programming , I tried but don't know what's wrong there ?

Comment: I agree with @Eric J -- this code does not make sense.  You are leaving something out.  However, the reason the buttons are null is because you never initialize them -- if this is a custom control you have to create them yourself, as op. to on a page where the page designer will set them up.

Comment: Hogan: I just drag and drop the buttons on MangoPagerControl.ascx....

Comment: How you register this control on the page?

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomMango" Namespace="MangoCustomControls" Assembly= "MangoCustomControls" %>

Comment: and then i am using like <CustomMango:MangoPagerControl  ID="MangoPager" runat="server" 
        ononpageritemclicked="MangoPagerControl1_OnPagerItemClicked" />

Comment: I put your code into a new web app.  One user control, one aspx page.  It works fine for me, no error.  And please don't assume that all SO users are male. kthx.

Comment: Finally, more information.  Can you please put that into the question?

Comment: Ok sorry for that , but I have tried to call the BindPager() method and do u see anything on thw web page ?

Comment: COuld you show how button is declared in the designer.cs file?

Comment: You're missing this on your aspx page         protected void MangoPagerControl1_OnPagerItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

Comment: Change <%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomMango" Namespace="MangoCustomControls" Assembly= "MangoCustomControls" %> to <%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomMango" TagName="MangoPagerControl" Src="path to ascx file" %>

Comment: sll: i have added that in the question..please have a look on that..

Comment: Can't see MangoPagerControl.ascx.designer.cs code

Comment: If you change the reference to your user control on the web page to this does your code compile and run?  <%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomMango" Namespace="MangoCustomControls" tagname= "MangoPagerControl" %>

Comment: No it says unrecognize tag prefix..

Comment: theGeek> i m using this: <%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomMango" Namespace="MangoCustomControls" Assembly= "MangoCustomControls" TagName="MangoPagerControl" %>

Comment: TheGeekYouNeed: are u still with the thread , just asking , don't mind ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely remove from the Register directive the namespace and assembly attributes as these attributes used for the server controls only. For registering user control you must specify Src where your ascx file placed, TagPrefix and TagName. [How to: Include a User Control in an ASP.NET Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx)

Comment: Hi  OneHalfTrackMindMan, i don't see my event now , how can i see that ?